# How to perform docker image release with maven

Tags: git, docker, maven, pipeline, release

Which commands best to use to perform pipeline commands to deploy *maven* and *docker* project to image repository and update *git* repository?

Steps:

1. Update versions in appropriate `pom.xml` (e.g. `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` → `1.1.0`)
2. *Locally* commit to git with comment `RELEASE: By $USER - prepare release 1.1.0` (so the version value is needed)
3. Tag with the version (e.g. `v1.1.0`)
4. Build project (e.g. `mvn clean package`) to have `target` folder prepared with new version
5. Create docker image (e.g. `docker build ...`)
6. Upload image to repo (e.g. `docker push ...`)
7. Update versions in appropriate pom.xml (e.g. `1.1.0` → `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`)
8. *Locally* commit to git with comment `RELEASE: By $USER - prepare for next development iteration`
9. Push to git repo with previously added tag

And additionally **don't run the maven build more than *once***
(e.g. `mvn release:prepare` is running it as well as `mvn package`) and **`pom.xml` should not be modified** (so no additional plugins inserted).
Ideally use *SemVer* strategy for version bumping.

Seems `maven-release-plugin` is either not sufficient (do more than required by itself) or some options must be added.

Comment: `mvn release:prepare` will do all for you except the docker part. It will change the version and add comments for release and build with the release version. target folder will have war/jar without SNAPSHOT. Then it will generate a tag and change the version and add a commit as well. After that, you can use the docker command to build the docker image.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I just don't want to `git push` if docker image fails to build.

Comment: And also how to get release version for tagging the docker image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exec-maven-plugin` along with the `maven-release-plugin`. You can set the profile from `maven-release-plugin` from that profile you can use `exec-maven-plugin` to execute the docker build/push command.

`pom.xml` configuration and how to use it.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
        <arguments>-Prelease</arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>docker-build</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <executable>docker</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>build -t sample:v${project.version} .</commandlineArgs>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>docker-push</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <executable>docker</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>push sample:v${project.version}</commandlineArgs>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

maven profile will make sure that without release normal commands will not use docker build/push. You can modify it as per your usage. Don't use `-DdryRun=true` as it will not commit in git but the command will build and push it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is also `dockerfile-maven-plugin`. But the point here is not to modify the `pom.xml` file as I mention in the question.

Comment: That can work with the docker command you want to run but again you need to modify the pom.xml. So the better way is to use shell script Which does all the above steps and you collect the version from pom.xml and pass it to the docker command.